# Splitting a graph into two cliques of different color

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose I have a complete graph where each edge is colored red or blue and each vertex is colored red or blue such that each edge touches a vertex of its own color.

I was told that if a complete graph has the above property, it can be split up into a blue clique and a red clique. However, consider the following image:

[image]

We can color $(a),(c)$ both blue and color $(b),(d)$ both red. This vertex coloring satisfies our property. However, if we try and *pull* the blue edges away from the red edges, we do not have a fully connected subgraph which is all red or blue.

Maybe I am misunderstanding what I was told?

I think it is true that if a graph can be split into a red clique and a blue clique, then the graph has my property detailed above. However, I do not think the converse is true. That is, it is not true that if a graph has my property, then it can be split into a red clique and a blue clique.

Comment: If you color $(a),(c)$ in blue and $(b),(d)$ in red like you said, you can split the graph in two 2-clique: the red one that contains $(a),(b)$ and the edge connecting them; the blue one containing $(b)$ and $(d)$and the relative edge.

Comment: @mrprottolo do you mind uploading some sort of picture of what you are saying? For whatever reason I am getting confused. I thought a graph split into a red clique and a blue clique relies only on the color of the edges and not the color of the vertices. Is this not true? Either way, I would still very much appreciate some sort of picture.

Comment: Also, $(a) -- (b)$ has a red edge and $(b) -- (d)$ also has a red edge. This is no blue clique so i'm not sure if your example satisfies the "split into two cliques of different color" property.

Comment: When you split the graph you have to consider two subsets of the vertices and the subgraph induced by the two subsets, you don't care about the edges connecting the two sets. In my example the sets are $\{a,c\}$ and $\{b,d\}$, so the cliques contain only one edge.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly about the property you are describing, but it sounds alot like Ramsey's theorem. Ramsey's theorem says that if you give a red-blue edge colouring to a sufficiently large complete graph then there exists a mono-chromatic red clique of size r and a mono-chromatic blue clique of size s. So perhaps the theorem you are thinking of has a requirement on the size of the complete graph?

Comment: @mrprottolo hm, okay. To be clear, this graph: http://imgur.com/GvQFXmv cannot be split into a red clique and a blue clique. Correct? Ben, the "property" I was talking about is sort of described in my post. You are correct that all of this is very similar to Ramsey Theorem stuff. And that is on purpose :).

Comment: Can you define 'blue clique' and 'red clique' ?  Does a red clique have to have all red vertices and all red vertices ?  Or just all red edges ?  Or just all red vertices ?